# Padrão que contribuiu com a confiabilidade de um software que precisa atender modelos complexos, como modelos multiempresas

Tags: design-pattern

**Dando como exemplo um software que precisa atender um modelo multiempresa, gostaria de saber de vocês se existe algum padrão adotado para lidar com esse tipo de situação?**

Descrevendo um pouco mais a condição, vamos dar como exemplo um software para contabilidade de empresas. Ele possui um cadastro de empresas porque precisa atender N empresas. De cada empresa teremos o cadastro de clientes, fornecedores entre outros.

Então a coisa precisa funcionar da seguinte forma:

1. O usuário terá acesso a determinadas empresas;
2. O usuário precisa setar para o sistema qual empresa ele estará realizando os processos de contabilidade;
3. O sistema apresenta os dados dos determinados cadastros que foram feitos para essa empresa e grava as novas entradas para a mesma.
4. O usuário pode a qualquer momento setar para o sistema que ele vai trabalhar para outra empresa e esse realiza as tarefas conforme já mencionado.

Então, dentro desta condição eu gostaria de saber se existe um padrão que auxilia nesse tipo de arquitetura de software de modo a ajudar a proteger as informações de empresa para empresa e ajudar também, claro, no desenvolvimento para ambientes que exijam esse tipo de controle?
**Ou seja, um padrão para assegurar que os dados de uma empresa "A" não serão misturados, apresentados ou excluídos em uma empresa B. Logo, contribuir na confiabilidade do software.**

Um exemplo, mesmo que pequeno, é bem vindo para facilitar a compreensão!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Acredito que o padrão [***multi-tenant***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) ("multi-inquilino") seria adequado para esse caso - ainda que seja um único operador de uma única empresa a acessar os diversos *tenants*. [Esse artigo](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/19067/cloud/entendendo-o-modelo-multi-tenancy/) descreve brevemente a filosofia por trás do *multitenancy*.

### Um exemplo real

Em vez de explicar a teoria, vou usar um projeto da minha empresa para exemplificar: nós construímos um software de gestão ([ERP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_integrado_de_gest%C3%A3o_empresarial)) voltado ao terceiro setor. A ideia era fazer instalação local nos clientes maiores, e oferecer como SaaS para os menores. Essa segunda etapa acabou não sendo posta em prática (ainda), mas o software foi todo construído segundo essa filosofia. No artigo citado, ela corresponderia ao modelo 4 ("Multi-inquilino via todo o stack de software compartilhado") - pois há apenas uma única instância da aplicação e um único BD.

Uma tabela `tenant` é o "coração" do sistema: uma linha dessa tabela é criada para cada cliente, e essa linha particiona todo o banco. Toda tabela adicional do sistema das duas uma:

1. possui uma chave estrangeira para uma linha dessa tabela; ou:
2. possui [pelo menos] uma chave estrangeira para outra tabela que satisfaça os itens 1 ou 2.

Exemplos (fictício; campo-chave do multitenancy marcado com *):

```
tenant         linha_atuacao                        projeto
id  nome       id  tenant* nome                     id linha* nome
---------      -------------------------------      ------------------------------
1   ONG A      1   1       Educação                 1  2      Educação Ambiental
2   ONG B      2   1       Meio Ambiente            2  2      Ecovilas
               3   2       Criança e Juventude      3  2      Amazônia Sustentável
```

A tabela de usuários também satisfaz a essa restrição, é claro. De modo que se um usuário está logado, ele pertence a um e somente um *tenant*. Cada visão que exige a autenticação do usuário (i.e. todas que lêem ou escrevem dados, basicamente...) obtém o ID desse *tenant* logo após a autenticação (i.e. ele fica armazenado em uma variável de sessão).

Resta então assegurar que uma requisição de um usuário não afetará acidentalmente os dados de um *tenant* que não é o seu. Há quem prefira fazer isso [dentro do próprio banco de dados](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/603/a-multi-tenant-strategy-using-yii-and-mysql/) (de modo que não é preciso confiar que os programadores não cometerão nenhum erro, pois as *views* a que eles têm acesso já vêm filtradas por *tenant*, tanto pra leitura quanto escrita), mas no meu caso eu fiz na camada de aplicação mesmo.

- O sistema usa o ORM do Django para acessar o banco de dados (i.e. sem SQL cru), então foi só uma questão de customizá-lo de modo a impor essa restrição. Fiz isso através de um *manager* (o objeto que traduz as chamadas da API para consultas SQL) padronizado pra todos os modelos.
- Ao preparar uma consulta de leitura, ele automaticamente adiciona os `join`s necessários para garantir que somente serão retornados resultados daquele *tenant*. Em vez de:

  ```
  Projeto.objects.filter(nome="Ecovilas")
  # select * from projeto where nome = "Ecovilas";
  ```

  Usa-se a API customizada filtrada por usuário:

  ```
  Projeto.objects.list(request.user).filter(nome="Ecovilas")
  # que internamente corresponde a:
  # Projeto.objects.filter(linha__tenant__id=request.user.tenant).filter(nome="Ecovilas")
  #
  # select * from projeto p join linha_atuacao l on p.linha = l.id
  #                         join tenant t on l.tenant = t.id
  #          where t.id = 1 and nome="Ecovilas";
  ```
- Ao preparar uma consulta de escrita, é um pouquinho mais complicado... Se o modelo for do tipo 1 (chave estrangeira pra `tenant`) ele automaticamente acrescenta o valor certo no campo. Depois, independentemente do tipo, ele faz uma consulta para cada chave estrangeira do modelo (como se estivesse fazendo uma leitura, nos moldes descritos acima) para assegurar que ela pertença ao mesmo *tenant*. Só então ele cria/atualiza/remove a linha de fato.

  ```
  linha = LinhaAtuacao.objects.create(nome="Dignidade e Direitos")
  # insert into linha_atuacao(nome) values("Dignidade e Direitos");

  Projeto.objects.create(linha=linha, nome="Creche X")
  # insert into projeto(linha_id, nome) values(3, "Creche X");
  ```

  Usando a API customizada:

  ```
  linha = LinhaAtuacao.objects.new(request.user)(nome="Dignidade e Direitos")
  # insert into linha_atuacao(tenant, nome) values(2, "Dignidade e Direitos");

  Projeto.objects.new(request.user)(linha=linha, nome="Creche X")
  # select * from linha_atuacao l join tenant t on l.tenant = t.id
  #          where t.id = 2 and l.id = 3;
  # insert into projeto(linha_id, nome) values(3, "Creche X");
  ```

  Se qualquer um (no caso só tem um) dos `select`s falhar - não retornar nenhum resultado - lança-se uma exceção em vez de fazer o `insert` (pois estava a se tentar atribuir uma linha de um *tenant* como chave estrangeira para outro *tenant*).

Um último detalhe: no caso de um terminal compartilhado (onde dois ou mais *tenants* podem acessar o mesmo sistema, um após o outro) é importante garantir que não sobre nada na IU quando um deles faz *logout*. Embora no meu caso esse cenário não estivesse previsto (no seu está - já que é o mesmo usuário que mexerá nos dados de várias empresas, uma por vez), eu optei por limpar todas as telas **e** recarregar a página (é uma aplicação web) logo após o *logout*, pro próximo que entrar não poder ler os dados do anterior.

### Acesso *"cross-tenant"*

No seu caso, fazer o mesmo usuário trocar de uma empresa pra outra é tranquilo: basta facilitar o processo de fazer *logout* com uma conta de usuário (de um *tenant*) e logo em seguida *login* com outra conta (de outro *tenant*), sem a necessidade de reautenticação.

No meu, o problema foi um pouco além: cada ONG possui diversos financiadores, e tem que prestar contas para cada um deles. Já um financiador pode prover recursos para várias ONGs, e ficou previsto que meu sistema eventualmente deveria dar acesso (leitura) pra um financiador aos dados de todos os seus convenentes - mas só aqueles dados que forem disponibilizados para tal pelo *tenant*. Que eu saiba, não há nada pronto nesse sentido, de modo que eu ainda estou quebrando a cabeça para cuidar de todos os detalhes (o projeto está atualmente em hiato).

### Referências adicionais

- Se você buscar no Google por ["microsoft multi-tenant"](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=microsoft%20multi-tenant) você encontrará uma série de artigos (em inglês) que discorrem sobre o assunto em profundidade (inclusive citando outras estratégias possíveis para se implementar *multitenancy*).
- Segundo meu sócio (que é formado em Administração, não é da área de Computação) mesmo antes do modelo SaaS e da ideia de *multitenancy* já existiam sistemas que empregavam o conceito de "mandantes" - no caso não necessariamente clientes à parte, mas sim entidades chave em torno do qual todos os outros dados giravam (bem isso que você está querendo). Entretanto, eu próprio não conheço bem do assunto nem tenho boas referências pra indicar. Mas segundo [esse artigo sobre o sistema da SAP](http://abap101.com/2014/01/13/mandt-campo-mandante-no-sap-entendendo-de-uma-vez-por-todas/) o conceito é esse mesmo, e parece corresponder quase que 100% ao padrão de *multitenancy* que eu conheço.

  Não sei se isso é só coisa da SAP ou é um padrão usado em outros lugares - nem se ele cumpre o objetivo de contribuir com a confiabilidade do sistema, como pedido na pergunta. Mas é uma referência a mais, se estiver disposto pode ir procurar mais informações.
- Por fim, se você tiver interesse em dar uma olhada, [aqui tem um link pro código do meu sistema](https://bitbucket.org/mgibsonbr/difutils/src/d9fcb06decee044a1c5cb638b2168eb0fcb14926/difutils_core/?at=default) (a parte que implementa *multitenancy* e, um pouco acima, outras coisinhas não relacionadas). Está extremamente mal-documentado e "gambiarrado", e não contém um exemplo completo que você possa baixar e já executar (pois somente a biblioteca de "utilitários" - e não o sistema completo - foi liberada como software livre), mas é melhor que nada... acho...

Comment: Rapaz, esse negócio de Stack Overflow não é brincadeira, não. A pessoa faz a pergunta mais específica do mundo e recebe a resposta mais especialista do planeta. Bra.vo!