# Usar múltiplas base de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, cakephp, mariadb

Não tenho muito conhecimento sobre banco de dados e nunca trabalhei com sistemas grandes... Estou criando uma aplicação com CakePHP que servirá de webservice para dois tipos de clientes distintos, um cliente é simples e só terá um relacionamento de tabela, o outro cliente é mais complexo e terá mais volume de dados e relacionamentos com tabelas (tabelas que não se relacionam com o cliente 1 e vice versa) e os dois clientes usarão aplicativos android diferentes.

Eu sempre usei 1 banco de dados para uma aplicação, e notei que sistemas como wordpress e joomla usam, mas imaginei, já que terei 2 aplicativos diferentes mas com o mesmo objetivo, seria melhor usar dois bancos de dados? (um para o cliente1 e outro pro cliente2).
Pela lógica seria melhor... Mas e se eu precisar ter uma tabela relacionada entre os dois tipos de clientes?

Estou usando MariaDB

Comment: [Relacionado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32270/215). Há vantagens e desvantagens de se usar bancos distintos pra clientes distintos, mas como no seu caso a *aplicação em si* é suficientemente distinta de um cliente pro outro, eu diria que bancos separados é o caminho mais recomendado. Ainda que eles tenham algumas tabelas semelhantes (mas não compartilhadas), é melhor repeti-las em um e outro banco, compartilhando somente os módulos de software que criam e gerenciam essas tabelas.

Comment: A performance ficaria melhor? levando em conta que os dois  bancos estão no mesmo servidor. O problema seria futuramente tivesse que implementar uma tabela relacionada entre os dois... Isso não tem como fazer né?

Comment: Não sei se a diferença de performance seria significativa. O fato do SGBD ser o mesmo ameniza as coisas - se fossem dois SGBDs diferentes, aí sim eles iam "brigar" pelos recursos da máquina... Quanto a uma tabela relacionando os dois, só no mesmo banco mesmo. Se você precisar de integridade referencial, é claro. Mas eu tenho dificuldade de imaginar um cenário em que os dados de dois clientes distintos precisem ser relacionados; são mesmo clientes distintos, ou apenas **usuários** distintos de um mesmo cliente? (tipo, dois departamentos numa mesma empresa).

Comment: são clientes distintos que usam o mesmo sistema, por exemplo no app do ifood tem o cliente que quer comprar comida e o cliente que quer anunciar, eles usam aplicativos diferentes e tem cadastros semelhantes, mas diferentes, o meu aplicativo segue esse modelo, com outro objetivo. Também não consigo imaginar um cenário que isso possa ocorrer, talvez não aconteça ou talvez sim. Também nunca vi alguém fazendo assim. Mas creio que vou separar os bancos, fica mais organizado, e é melhor na hora de realizar backups

Comment: @mgibsonbr cria uma resposta para o conteúdo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando se tem uma única aplicação e vários clientes diferentes, pode ser vantajoso ter um único banco de dados atendendo a todos (como você afirma ser o caso do Wordpress e Joomla). Isso não vem sem desafios, entretanto - veja minha resposta a [essa pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32270/215) para um exemplo real de como isso pode ser feito, e dos cuidados que precisam ser tomados para os dados de um cliente não se misturarem com os de outro. [Esse artigo](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/19067/cloud/entendendo-o-modelo-multi-tenancy/) sobre *multi-tenancy* cita outras estratégias possíveis, como usar a mesma aplicação mas bancos diferentes, ou mesmo instâncias separadas da aplicação para cada cliente (estratégia que eu próprio usei em um projeto recente).

Se é ou não vantajoso manter um único banco para todos os clientes, seja do ponto de vista do desempenho ou da manutenção, é discutível. Pessoalmente, creio que um único banco traz mais agilidade para cadastrar e descadastrar clientes (basta inserir/apagar registros de uma tabela, em vez de criar/destruir bancos inteiros), enquanto múltiplos bancos torna mais simples fazer *backups* (não é preciso se preocupar com dados de um cliente indo parar nos backups de outro) e *talvez* simplifique o crescimento em escala (dá pra escalonar sistemas com banco único também - através de particionamento "vertical" ou "horizontal" - mas não tenho experiência prática suficiente para comentar).

No seu caso, entretanto, o fato dos clientes - e da aplicação que os servirá - serem substancialmente diferentes um do outro é praticamente o argumento decisivo para se escolher ter bancos separados; um fator complicador na arquitetura *multi-tenant* é justamente como customizar a experiência de um cliente sem "quebrar" o sistema para todos  os outros (se o cliente quer um campo a mais na tabela X, você não pode simplesmente colocar, pois do contrário todos os outros também teriam de receber aquele campo). E nesse caso o fator está presente desde o início, pois você *sabe* que vai precisar de estruturas de dados (e código) diferentes...

Quanto a um cliente precisar referenciar o outro na sua base de dados, eu diria pra não se preocupar muito com isso: em primeiro lugar porque esse caso não está previsto, é só uma especulação "e se?", e até onde eu saiba esse não é um cenário nem um pouco comum; segundo, porque mesmo que no final acabe precisando, a falta de integridade referencial (i.e. não poder criar chaves estrangeiras de um banco pra outro, com garantia de integridade) não deve ser um problema tão grande que não possa ser tratado na sua camada de aplicação.