# Diferença entre get_context_data e get_queryset e melhoria de códigos (Django)

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-generic-views

eu queria saber a diferença entre get_context_data e get_queryset.

E gostaria de saber a opinião de vocês sobre os meus códigos.

O que está certo e o que está errado neles?

https://github.com/rg3915/vendas/blob/master/vendas_project/vendas/views.py#L121-L132

```
class SaleDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'vendas/sale/sale_detail.html'
    model = Sale

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        s = Sale.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        sd = SaleDetail.objects.all().filter(sale=s)
        context = super(SaleDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['count'] = sd.count()
        context['Sale'] = s
        context['Itens'] = sd
        return context
```

https://github.com/rg3915/vendas/blob/master/vendas_project/vendas/views.py#L74-L88

```
def get_queryset(self):
    p = Product.objects.all()
    q = self.request.GET.get('search_box')
    # buscar por produto
    if q is not None:
        p = p.filter(product__icontains=q)
    # filtra produtos em baixo estoque
    if self.request.GET.get('filter_link', False):
        p = p.filter(stock__lt=F('stock_min'))
    return p
```

O que pode ser melhorado nesses códigos?

Answer (score 3):

Esses métodos têm propósitos totalmente diferentes:

- `get_context_data` fornece os dados do contexto a ser usado ao renderizar um template. Isso não envolve necessariamente o ORM, de modo que você poderia por exemplo criar um *view* que não consultasse nenhuma tabela do seu BD, apenas reunisse alguns parâmetros de alguma outra fonte e os colocasse num formato apropriado para serem usados no template.
- `get_queryset` tem como objetivo criar um `QuerySet` "básico" que pode ou não ser "refinado" pelo código consumidor. Ou seja, se você tem alguma operação que quer fazer a todos os *query sets* antes dos mesmos serem usados (em um projeto passado eu pré-filtrava os modelos baseados num campo [*"tenant"*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32275/215)) você pode fazê-lo nesse método. O que será feito com o resultado depois, depende do caso (em um `ListView`, ele vai acabar sendo usado também em um template, mas outros usos sem envolver templates também seriam possíveis).

Eu não tenho experiência com *views* genéricas para opinar sobre seus códigos, mas à primeira vista não há nenhum problema nos mesmos, nem nada que pudesse ser melhorado. *Talvez* fosse possível usar uma única *query* para consultar a venda e seus itens, em vez de duas *queries* como está sendo feito, mas não tenho certeza se é possível e/ou se traria alguma vantagem significativa na performance. E o primeiro exemplo me parece que falhará se não houver venda com a chave primária consultada, você está tratando essa possibilidade de alguma forma? (i.e. para a exceção não propagar e resultar num erro `500`)

Comment: Obrigado pela opinião @mgibsonbr