# Um banco de dados ou um banco de dados individual para cada usuário?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Bom pessoal, desde já agradeço por estarem aqui me ajudando, vamos lá.

Estou com uma dúvida q pra mim ta sendo difícil ter respostas.

Digamos q estou criando um sistema, OK. Nesse sistema cada empresa teram usuário visitando sua página, e aí q vem minha dúvida :/

Essas empresas teram as mesmas bases de informações, porém cada uma com informações diferentes.

Aí fico na dúvida de, faço apenas um banco de dados com todas essas empresas e seus respectivos itens relacionados a sua empresa

Ou

Um banco de dados para cada empresa, LEMBRANDO q todas irão aparecer em uma única página.

(Pra mim um banco de dados seria o certo, mas aí vem aquela de pesar por ele suportar todas as empresas e seus itens)

O que vcs tem a dizer pessoal ?

Comment: [Outra pergunta relacionada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32270/215) (caso você opte por ter um único banco de dados atendendo a múltiplos clientes)

Comment: Cara com esse post q VC mencionou eu não entendi muito bem. . de acordo com ele o correto é trabalhar com apenas 1 banco de dados dando suporte as empresas com seus itens relacionados a base de chave estrangeira. Meu medo é de pesar muito por acumular muita informação ... Isso acontecerá ?

Comment: O problema deste tipo de pergunta é que ela é muito ampla e praticamente fora de escopo. OU dá para postar uma resposta bem genérica ou precisa ter tanto detalhe que virará consultoria. E detalhe falta na pergunta. Eu até entendo que quem ainda está aprendendo tem dificuldade de lidar com isso, mas não existe uma resposta absoluta para isto. E uma específica depende de consultoria completa. É melhor fechar como duplicata porque aquele é mais ou menos canônica para o assunto. Dúvidas bem mais específicas, com um foco ainda podem ser feitas. O que tinha que ser dito no geral, já foi lá.

Comment: Está difícil ter respostas porque elas não existem. Não da forma que espera.

Comment: @PedroSoares Pode acontecer, sim. Mas não otimize prematuramente - a menos que você esteja trabalhando com um banco de dados gigantesco (e quando você estiver, com certeza já terá mais experiência, do contrário é impossível colocar um banco desses nas mãos de um iniciante), é muito provável que esse problema não apareça tão cedo. E quando aparecer, existem técnicas de particionamento que permitem separar os clientes em bancos diferentes (ou outras estratégias). Entretanto, note que não tem resposta certa, um banco ou vários bancos. Existem somente prós e contras, e isso você vai ter que pesar.

Comment: Poxa :/ só precisava de um conselho de quem já é  experiente